# Error while writing csv file to S3 bucket using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm using pyspark version 2.4.5 and boto3 for access to AWS services. 
Create SparkSession

```
spark = SparkSession\
.builder\
.config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.5") \
.master("local")\
.appName("MyApp")\
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", credentials.access_key)\
.config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", credentials.secret_key)\
.getOrCreate()
```

- Dataframe contains records (also for the sake of test I tried to write only a column)
- IAM user has S3FullAccess credentials

I've got an error while writing the dataframe to S3 bucket

```
output_path = "s3a://bucket_name/sample.csv"
df.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").csv(output_path)
```

Error

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 output_path = "s3a://udacity-project-datalake-boobooka/sample"
>   ----> 2 df.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").csv(output_path)
>
> c:\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in csv(self,
>   path, mode, compression, sep, quote, escape, header, nullValue,
>   escapeQuotes, quoteAll, dateFormat, timestampFormat,
>   ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace,
>   charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, encoding, emptyValue)
>       930                        charToEscapeQuoteEscaping=charToEscapeQuoteEscaping,
>       931                        encoding=encoding, emptyValue=emptyValue)
>   --> 932         self._jwrite.csv(path)
>       933 
>       934     @since(1.5)
>
> c:\python\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in **call**(self,
>   *args)    1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1256         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1258     1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> c:\python\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
>        61     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        62         try:
>   ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
>        64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        65             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> c:\python\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in
>   get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       329             else:
>       330                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o108.csv. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)

and so forth

Comment: Do you have s3fs installed? Try installing it and then execute the code again.

Comment: No, it hasn't been installed. I've installed but it doesn't help